# Export html content to Excel in IE8 using javascript /Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, internet-explorer-8

I am having below sample code to export the html content to excel. it is working fine in chrome browser. but it is not working in any IE browser 8/9 version. please refer below code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("[id$=excellink]").click(function(e) {
                    alert("$('div[id$=dvData]').html()");
                    window.open('data:application/vnd.xls,' + encodeURIComponent( $('div[id$=dvData]').html()));
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        </script>
        <body>
            <br/>
            <div id="dvData">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Billing System</th>
                        <th>Market Code</th>
                        <th>Payment Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>RED</td>
                        <td>222</td>
                        <td>$103.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>BLUE</td>
                        <td>111</td>
                        <td>$13.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>GREEN</td>
                        <td>555</td>
                        <td>$143.00</td>  
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <input type="button" id="excellink" value="Excel" />

        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx ?

Comment: @tiriana could you please update the sample or demo for this